# Laravel Socialite + Making API calls after login

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

Laravel 5, Socialite, and google/apiclient packages.

Source code: https://github.com/svpernova09/meatings

I have socialite working fine with Google for logging users in.

I'm trying to make an API call in a different method to fetch Calendar events as the logged in user. I'm getting stuck with what tokens to use where.

The error I'm getting is:

> "error" : "invalid_grant",
>
> "error_description" : "Code was already redeemed."

My method:

```
public function show($user_id)
{
    $user = $this->user->find($user_id);

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'));
    $client->setClientSecret(env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'));
    $client->setRedirectUri(env('GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL'));
    
    $client->authenticate($user->code);
    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

    $calendarId = $user->calendar_id;
    $optParams = array(
        'maxResults' => 5,
        'orderBy' => 'startTime',
        'singleEvents' => TRUE,
        'timeMin' => date('c'),
    );
    $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
    $events = [];
    if (count($results->getItems()) > 0) {
        foreach ( $results->getItems() as $event ) {
            $events[] = $event;
        }
    }

    return view('users.calendar')->with('events', $events);
}
```

The Laravel output is:

> Google_Auth_Exception in OAuth2.php line 127:
> Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'

$user-code looks like: 4/hfPzDrOHyaEv3asdfadsfasdfDw72nXIl0rt2boUpGj7hM.Um5wPgCeasdfasdfafd1t6qxkmwI

Any guidance would be great. I'm not getting anywhere with the google guides.

Comment: At this point, aren't you already authenticated? It says that the code was already redeemed and you already have an access token.

Comment: Yes, the user is authenticated already, I have the token that Socialite gets back, but I get 'invalid grant' errors when I try to auth the next API request (this method)

Comment: @Joe Try refreshing the token by revoking access and reauthenticating. You may also have to use a different scope. By default, socialite only uses a few scopes, I believe _profile_ and _email_. You have to add the _calendar_ or _calendar.readonly_ scopes per the Google API docs.

Answer (score 1):

Calendar uses a different scope than social login. You have to ask for permission again. You can check the documentation of the [Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) and try it out on [Google Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/).

Also Google returns *"Code was already redeemed."* because you already have an access token for the public information of the user with your code.